# Do "al(t)" and "aul" sound the same?

Tags: pronunciation

Do the combinations "**al(t)**" and "**aul**" sound the same in speech?

- Salt, Halt, Walt...
- Fault, Vault, Assault...

And are they always pronounced as "**olt**"?

Edit: Notice that the word "**alter(native)**" can be pronounced "**olt**", "**ult**" and "**elt**".

Comment: What about your p*al* P*aul*?

Comment: I say "salt", "halt", "Walt", "fault", "vault" with a BrE short "o" /ɒ/.  My dad says them with "aw" /ɔ:/.  Neither of us distinguishes the vowels in "salt", "halt" from those in "fault" etc.  And both of us use /ɔ:/ for "all", "ball", "call", "fall", "law", "door".) With polysyllables our usage varies more - in my case between /ɒ/ and /ʌ/ in "assault" between /ɔ:/ and /ʌ/ in "alter", "assault", and between /ɒ/ and /ɔ:/ in "Baltic", depending how carefully I'm speaking. However, I can't rule out that some speakers might distinguish the vowels in "salt"/"halt" from those in "fault"/"vault".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect these pronunciations vary with regional dialect.

I pronounce "salt", "halt", "Walt", "fault", and "vault" with very similar vowel sounds.  I pronounce "Assault" with two schwas ("uh-suhlt").

It seems that the five words that sound similar are all having their vowels modified by the "lt".

But notice that there are similarly spelled vowels that sound very different:

- "shalt"
- "half", "halve", "calf", "calve"
- "Al", "Cal", "Sal"